# local storage and jquery toggle

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I could not get jquery cookie to work with multiple divs.

What I need is when a user clicks a link and then returns to index page, I need the menu link that they were viewing to show. Right now it is collapsed when they return to the index page.

I am now using Local Storage in my example. Below is what I have but that is not working.

```
    <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>


     <script type="text/javascript">
      function toggleDiv(divId) {
         $("#"+divId).toggle();
         }
       </script>

       <script>
       $('"#"+divId').on('click',function(){
           $(this).children().slideToggle().promise().done(function() {
             var vis = $(this).is(':visible') ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
              localStorage.setItem('"#"+divId', vis);
              });
                 });
            </script>
```

Portion of html

```
       <div class="box2right"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent2');">HOW TO USE THE SYSTEM</a>
         <div id="myContent2" class="hidden">

         <a href="html/systemuse_startofdayprocedures.html">Start of Day Procedures</a> 
        <p> <a href="html/systemuse_keyboard.html">Understanding the Keyboard</a> </p> 
             </div>


           <div class="box3right"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent3');">CIVIL INFORMATION FILE</a>
              <div id="myContent3" class="hidden">
              <a href="html/civil_screen1.html">Screen 1</a> - Screen that contains case information. 
             <p><a href="html/civil_supremecourt.html">Supreme Court</a>  </p>
              </div>



          <div class="box4right"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">CRIMINAL INFORMATION FILE</a>
            <div id="myContent" class="hidden">
            <a href="html/criminal_screen1.html">Screen 1</a> - This screen contains the case information.
                  <p>
             </div>
```

I have additional divs but I won't include all of them.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using `('"#"+divId')`?

Comment: trying to get my div to show when they return